# Does not update Firebase data when activity returns - Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, firebase, android-cardview

I am using Bottom Navigation View and in one of the options we display Firebase data, with a CardView.

But when I get out of this activity, and come back, either with the device back button or the activity arrow, it does not work. Does not display anything.

What could be wrong?

Prints: 
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Code Bottom Navigation View:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView =(BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.ic_home:

                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_explore:

                        Intent intentExplore = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ExploreActivity.class);
                        intentExplore.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intentExplore);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_calendar:
                        Intent intentAgenda = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AgendamentoActivity.class);
                        intentAgenda.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intentAgenda);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_person:
                        Intent intentuser = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, OpcoesUsuarioActivity.class);
                        intentuser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intentuser);
                        break;

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Note: In tests in activities without Bottom Navigation or with SlidingTabs, it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you are using a wrong approach about the `BottomNavigationView` you need to use [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) not `Activities` check [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-bottom-navigation-view-example/). About your problem when you are clicking on any item you puts your activity `onPause` that mean the activity still at the stack but is not visible, when clicking back you just finish the current activity and back to the last one with calling the `onResume` method the `onCreate` is not called, so put your `RecyclerView` work at your `onResume` method, or call `finish()` when leaving the activity.